# Multiple result sets from a stored procedure with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, function

Getting unexpected result from function. I just need two result sets from the code that I have written in the function but instead getting some unnamed portal issue.

I have tried same using cursor.Which is as follows.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION User(param_state CHAR(10)) RETURNS SETOF refcursor AS $$
    DECLARE
      ref1 refcursor;           -- Declare cursor variables
      ref2 refcursor;                             
    BEGIN
      OPEN ref1 FOR select *  from Table1
    WHERE code = param_state;
    RETURN NEXT ref1;                                                                              

      OPEN ref2 FOR select * from Table2
    WHERE  code= param_state;

    RETURN NEXT ref2; 

    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Expected output should be to 2 result set of 2 column each

```
-------------------
|party_code | limit|
|------------------|
|T001       |  120 |
-------------------

-------------------
|party_code | Sal  |
|------------------|
|T001       | 1000 |
-------------------
```

But the output is

```
---------------------
|<unnamed portal 34>|
---------------------
|<unnamed portal 35>|
```

Comment: could you please show us what is the data you have in your tables and what you exactly want in the end of your procedure?

Comment: In the expected output section I have mentioned the same. It is just that when I call the function using - **select User('RP61')** it gives **unnamed portal 32** instead of values which are in the table.

Comment: Maybe there is another way to do what you want to do. Cursors have to be banished when you can. So, simple : what have you in your Table1 and in your table two. And for a given param_state : what do you want in your output.

Comment: You seem to be using "psql".  This is how psql displays refcursors.  It doesn't recurse into the cursors, it just displays the cursor itself.  Is getting "psql" to display things in one particular way really your goal here?

Comment: Yes, it displays the cursor itself. I just want multiple result set when I execute function, not necessarily using "psql".

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to name your cursors ..

```
...
DECLARE
  ref1 refcursor := 'mycursor1' ;
  ref2 refcursor := 'mycursor2' ;
...
```

.. and fetch the results using their names ..

```
SELECT * FROM "User"('T001');

BEGIN; 
  FETCH ALL FROM mycursor2;
  FETCH ALL FROM mycursor1;
END;


FETCH ALL FROM mycursor2;
 code | Sal  
------+------
 T001 | 1000
(1 row)

postgres=# FETCH ALL FROM mycursor1;
 code | limit 
------+-------
 T001 |   120
(1 row)
```